# findViewById() is returning null for custom view - Android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-custom-view

Let me start by saying this: I've already looked through all of the other threads on this issue and combed Google for an answer, but nothing has helped me.

I have a layout that contains a custom view that is added at runtime. My custom view has the `super(context, attrs)` constructor.

Custom view:

```
public CustomLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initialize some variables...
}
```

I add views to my activity with the following method:

```
public void addNewView (boolean isEmpty) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    if (isEmpty) {
        View v = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_custom_layout, layoutContainer, true);
        viewTracker++;
    }
    }
}
```

If I use findViewById for my custom view in the `addNewView()` method above then all is well. However, if I try to use findViewById anywhere else in the activity after the view has been inflated (and obviously after `setContentView`) I get a null pointer. I've also tried `someView.findViewById()` which doesn't work. I'm stumped. Any ideas?

Logcat shows a null pointer, but nothing more:

```
02-16 06:56:10.681: E/AndroidRuntime(11360): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-16 06:56:10.681: E/AndroidRuntime(11360): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-16 06:56:10.681: E/AndroidRuntime(11360): at com.nutrifit.Fragments.WorkoutPlannerPopup.resetOtherView(WorkoutPlannerPopup.java:404)
02-16 06:56:10.681: E/AndroidRuntime(11360): at com.nutrifit.customviews.CustomLinearLayout.onTouchEvent(CustomLinearLayout.java:43)
02-16 06:56:10.681: E/AndroidRuntime(11360): at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7239)
02-16 06:56:10.681: E/AndroidRuntime(11360): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2168)
02-16 06:56:10.681: E/AndroidRuntime(11360): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1903)
02-16 06:56:10.681: E/AndroidRuntime(11360): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
```

Here's my custom view in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.nutrifit.customviews.CustomLinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/exercise_container_0"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/wpp_background_border" >

<ImageView android:id="@+id/delete_button_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/wpp_background_border" />
...more android child views

</com.nutrifit.customviews.CustomLinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you sure that setContentView is assigning correctly and not throwing an uncaught exception? Post the output of logcat and all your code.

Comment: @Kerry To the best of my knowledge setContentView is assigning correctly. The only exception that is thrown is a null pointer when I try to use findViewById. Which code would you like me to post? The activity that contains this is 450+ lines of code.

Comment: Please paste your xml where you are declaring your custom view.

Comment: Thanks, looks ok, but i'm not sure if i understand your problem. You want to add many of your custom linear layouts with it's contents at runtime? Or maybe do you want to add some child's to your custom linear layout?

Comment: @MichałZ. Sure thing. Sorry, I wasn't very clear about that. I have several XML layouts like the one above. In my activity I have the root layout. What I want is to add layouts like the one above to my activity's root layout at runtime and then reference them later in my code. But, when I try to use findViewById on the custom views (or even android views within the layout above) I get a null pointer. I think it might have something to do with the LayoutInflater, but I'm unsure.

Comment: where is the findViewById call?

Comment: @androiddeveloper Well, I've tried it in several different spots, but the only time it works is if I call it right after I inflate the layout (like in the method above). I've also found that even if I store a view in an instance variable and try to modify later in the code it also gives a null pointer.

Answer (score 3):

Where is the `addNewView()` method being called? From my understanding, if you do a `findViewById()` in the constructor of a custom view, you could get a `null`. I haven't found an authoritative reference that states when it is safe to call `findViewById()` in a custom view, but I normally do it in `onFinishInflate()` or later.

Comment: The `addNewView()` method is being called from a button click. So, the layout should be inflated. I sort of solved the problem. I ended up figuring out that it had something to do with my custom view. However, I have no clue what in my custom view would make that happen - I had the correct constructor and nothing else was special about the view. Thanks for your help though!